# make ctrl+enter add semicolon to the end of the line

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Ctrl+enter in sublimetext is a default shortcut to create a new line, no matter in what position your cursor are in the current line. However, sometimes I need to add a semicolon at the end of the current line before jump to a new line.

How can i make the "ctrl+enter" shortcut add a semicolon to the end of the current line before create a new line? Is it even possible?

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After AGS's answer, I solved my problem with similar approach. You can do this:

**1. Create a macro file in the folder `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` with:**

> `[
>       {
>           "args":
>           {
>               "to": "hardeol"
>           },
>           "command": "move_to"
>       },
>       {
>           "args":
>           {
>               "characters": ";"
>           },
>           "command": "insert"
>       },
>       {
>           "args":
>           {
>               "characters": "\n"
>           },
>           "command": "insert"
>       }
>   ]`

**2. Then edit your keybindings `Preferences > Key Bindings - User`. Add this:**

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/FILENAME.sublime-macro"} },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply modify the macro `/Default/Add Line.sublime-macro` to insert the semicolon.

From this

```
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol"}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"}}
]
```

to this

```
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol"}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ";\n"}}
]
```

Comment: I couldnt find this macro file. but your answer helped me. Thank you