# How to use conditions/context in ST3 macros?

Tags: macros, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to modify the Ctrl+Enter-macro so that it appends a semicolon to the end of the line before writing a newline, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715141/). 
The basic solution is pretty simple

```
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol"}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ";\n"}}
]
```

, however, it has two problems:

---

**1)** If there is already a semicolon at eol, it will be duplicated. Is there a way to include a condition of ( preceding_text == ";" ) similar to keybindings'

```
{ "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": ";$" }
```

and have the macro run one of two different insert commands depending on that?

---

**2)** As it is, the plugin runs independent of language, also inserting semicolons, for example, in html. Again, is there a way to make inserting the semicolon optional depending on the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pretty good workaround. I still don't know, if it's possible to add this kind of condition in the macro itself, but it can be substituted by adding the conditions in the key-bindings.

First, create a second macro "Packages/User/Add Line Semicolon.sublime-macro" with

```
[
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardeol"}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ";\n"}}
]
```

In the user-keybindings add

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/Add Line Semicolon.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": ";$", "match_all": false },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "(source.css, source.scss) - comment", "match_all": false },
    ]
},
```

This listens to the same keys as the normal ctrl+enter, but calls the new macro and only triggers if certain conditions are met.

First, the text after the cursor may not end with a semicolon. If there's already a semicolon at the end of line, this binding will not trigger and the shortcut will be passed through to the default binding instead. Note that, since it only checks the text after the caret, this will not work if your cursor is already at the end of the line.

Secondly, the position of the caret must have the appropriate scope. For this example, I just included css and scss files, and it only matches if you're not currently in a comment. Again, if the condition fails, the shortcut will be passed through to the default macro.

Comment: User-created plugins, macros, and whatnot should always be placed in `Packages/User`, not any other directory.

Comment: It's placed in "%appdata%/Sublime Text 3…" . I started the script there since it originally was supposed to replace the normal New Line macro without changing anything else. (files with the same relative path, but in %appdata% are preferred over those in %installdir%, but not overwritten by updates). Technically, it should have been moved to User the moment I made it a unique script, but I consider them to be similar enough to be worth keeping together.